# Update one field in all documents and all collections

Tags: mongodb

I want to update one field in all documents and all collections in my mongo. All collections and documents already hold the field. I simply want to update it with one call. Is this possible?

What I can do of course is to use `updateMany`on all collections by hand:

```
db.getCollection("myCollection1").updateMany({}, 
  {"$set" : {"name" : "Tobi"}}
)
```

This is possible but I have a couple of collections and want to minimize the probability for errors. Therefore, I want to automate it in some way. Is there a way e.g. to loop over all collections and do the `updateMany` command?

Something like this:

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(
  function(collection) {
    collection.updateMany({}, {"$set" : {"name" : "Tobi"}})
  }
)
```

Comment: You basically answered your own question in your question.

Comment: It is `db.getCollection(collection).updateMany` within the loop. `collection` is a string there.

Comment: Thanks, I think I was on the right track :)